# How to check that file is saved to hard during TCP sending?

Tags: python, linux, file, tcp

I send many files over TCP from PC(windows) to Server(Linux).

When I process files on server sometimes I get error, since file is corrupted or has zero size, because it is still undergoes 'saving' to hard disc.

I process files in python, grabbing like this:

```
file_list = sorted(glob('*.bin'))
for file in file_list:
    file_size = os.path.getsize(file)
    if file_size > min_file_size:
       do_process(file)
```

How to make it in proper way, i.e make sure, that file is ok.
I cant choose right min_file_size, since files have different sizes..

May be I should copy it to another folder ant then process them?

** I'm using SCP to copy files. So on the server side how can I be sure(some linux hints), that file is ok, to move it to directory, which will be processing? Sometimes by typing ls I see files, whch is not fully sent yet.. so how can I rename them?

Comment: What software or protocol is used for _TCP sending_?  It is definitely a good idea to save into a different directory or under a different filename until the transfer is complete, and then (atomically) rename the file before using it.

Comment: * I use SCP paramiko

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Im using python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fuser` command to check whether the file is currently being accessed by any process, as follows:

```
import subprocess
...
file_list = sorted(glob('*.bin'))
for file in file_list:
    result = subprocess.run(['fuser','--silent',file])
    if result.returncode != 0:
        do_process(file)
```

The `fuser` command will terminate with a non-0 return code if the file is not being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with TCP. You are basically asking how to synchronize two processes in a way that if one writes the file the other will only use it once it is completely written and closed by the other.

One common way is to let the first process (writer) use a temporary file name which is not expected by the second process (reader) and to rename the file to the expected one after the file was closed. Other ways involve using file locking. One can also have a communication between the two processes (like a pipe or socketpair) which is used to explicitly inform the reader once the writer has finished and which file was written.

Comment: Im using SCP, so how can I be sure, that file is ok, before rename it?

Comment: @delkov The receiving process must know the size of the file being received. The sender must also send the file size before the file contents.